# What is "a raw power trip"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can the political frame unravel the secret of the group’s phenomenal performance?
Possibly group members were motivated more by power than by money:“There’s a big high in here somewhere for me that I don’t fully understand. Some of it’s a raw power trip. The reason I work is because I win” (p. 179). They were encouraged to circumvent formal channels to advance group interests:“If you can’t get what you need from some manager at 
your level in another department, go to his boss—that’s the way to get things done”(p. 191).

Source: [Reframing Organization](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=Can%20the%20political%20frame%20unravel%20the%20secret%20of%20the%20group%E2%80%99s%20phenomenal%20performance?%20Possibly%20group%20members%20were%20motivated%20more%20by%20power%20than%20by%20money:%E2%80%9CThere%E2%80%99s%20a%20big%20high%20in%20here%20somewhere%20for%20me%20that%20I%20don%E2%80%99t%20fully%20understand.%20Some%20of%20it%E2%80%99s%20a%20raw%20power%20trip.%20The%20reason%20I%20work%20is%20because%20I%20win%E2%80%9D%20(p.%20179).%20They%20were%20encouraged%20to%20circumvent%20formal%20channels%20to%20advance%20group%20interests:%E2%80%9CIf%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20get%20what%20you%20need%20from%20some%20manager%20at%20your%20level%20in%20another%20department,%20go%20to%20his%20boss%E2%80%94that%E2%80%99s%20the%20way%20to%20get%20things%20done%E2%80%9D(p.%20191).&source=bl&ots=oxN4ybBo-K&sig=ACfU3U2QfMvHv7KGhhXlEnic_2x0itxc7Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGvrKqlaniAhUNUd4KHRGEDXgQ6AEwCnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=Can%20the%20political%20frame%20unravel%20the%20secret%20of%20the%20group%E2%80%99s%20phenomenal%20performance%3F%20Possibly%20group%20members%20were%20motivated%20more%20by%20power%20than%20by%20money%3A%E2%80%9CThere%E2%80%99s%20a%20big%20high%20in%20here%20somewhere%20for%20me%20that%20I%20don%E2%80%99t%20fully%20understand.%20Some%20of%20it%E2%80%99s%20a%20raw%20power%20trip.%20The%20reason%20I%20work%20is%20because%20I%20win%E2%80%9D%20(p.%20179).%20They%20were%20encouraged%20to%20circumvent%20formal%20channels%20to%20advance%20group%20interests%3A%E2%80%9CIf%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20get%20what%20you%20need%20from%20some%20manager%20at%20your%20level%20in%20another%20department%2C%20go%20to%20his%20boss%E2%80%94that%E2%80%99s%20the%20way%20to%20get%20things%20done%E2%80%9D(p.%20191).&f=false)

Comment: Are you sure that's "some of it's"? That doesn't look right though. I can't see the referenced page.

Comment: Yes, I am. Click on the link I gave, you'll see it near the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The word **raw** here is being used according to [definition 4 c](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raw), meaning "not tempered : unbridled."  And **power trip** is [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/power%20trip) as "something that a person does for the pleasure of using power to control other people."

So a "raw power trip" is something that someone does for the sheer pleasure of using power over others **without any restraints** (that's the "raw" or unbridled part).

In the context of your quote, the author is trying to explain why they enjoy their work. They say that "there's a big high," meaning a feeling of exhilaration or euphoria, but they do not "completely understand" the source of that euphoria.  However, "some of it" (meaning the euphoria) is caused by this **raw power trip**.